# Does my multilevel modelling create false replication and spurious precision at the highest level?

Tags: bayesian, multilevel-analysis, bugs

I am fitting a 3-level model in Bugs. The data are in long format. The data consists of 885 Treatments in 1:3 COURSEs of treatment in 108 Patients (MRNs).

```
model{

for(DMRN in 1:NMRN) {

  RMRN[DMRN] ~ dnorm(meanMRN[DMRN], TMRN)
  meanMRN[DMRN] <- intercept

  for(DCOURSE in SMRN[DMRN]:(SMRN[DMRN+1]-1)){

    RCOURSE[DCOURSE] ~ dnorm(meanCOURSE[DCOURSE], TCOURSE)
    meanCOURSE[DCOURSE] <- RMRN[DMRN]

    for(Dobservations in SCOURSE[DCOURSE]:(SCOURSE[DCOURSE+1]-1)){

      totalEEG[Dobservations] ~ dpois(meanobservations[Dobservations])
      log(meanobservations[Dobservations]) <- RCOURSE[DCOURSE] +inprod(betaobservations[] , Xobservations[Dobservations,])

    }#observations
  }#COURSE
}#MRN


# priors

intercept ~ dflat()
betaobservations[1] ~ dflat()
betaobservations[2] ~ dflat()
betaobservations[3] ~ dflat()

TMRN <- pow(SDMRN, -2)
SDMRN ~ dunif(0, 100)
TCOURSE <- pow(SDCOURSE, -2)
SDCOURSE ~ dunif(0, 100)

} # model
```

I am worried that my covariates in the model - one of which (Age) varies only at the top level - are replicated in long format and therefore "counted more" in BUGS and giving me spuriously precise posterior distributions. However, obviously it is not contributing any variation at the lowest level (within patient).

```
bgs.toteeg<-glmmBUGS(formula = totalDuration ~ AnaDose+ AgeYrs + log.workDose, effects=c("MRN", "COURSE"), family="poisson", data=book,  modelFile="model.bug")
source("getInits.R")
startingValues=bgs.toteeg$startingValues
myResult = bugs(bgs.toteeg$ragged, getInits ,model.file = "model.bug", n.chain = 3, n.iter = 10000,  n.burnin = 1000, parameters.to.save = names(getInits()),n.thin = 10, debug=T)
```

AgeYrs is included as a covariate here but obviously doesn't vary across patient-treatment, but only between patients. All of the other covariates are different values for each treatment.

The results back in R are:

```
> mysummary$scalars[, c("mean", "2.5%","97.5%")]
                mean        2.5%    97.5%
intercept 3.36308519 3.220175000 3.473550
SDCOURSE  0.04677978 0.001696725 0.094267
SDMRN     0.31222407 0.265697500 0.357700
> signif(mysummary$betas[, c("mean","2.5%", "97.5%")], 3)
               mean     2.5%   97.5%
MHXKG        0.0605 -0.01360 0.14200
AgeYrs       0.0027  0.00162 0.00407
log.workDose 0.0457  0.03170 0.06000
```

How does the model prevent spurious replication of repeated measures which in this case, are exactly the same across patient treatments, but only differ between patients, therefore at the COURSE" level there will be a low or no variability, at the Patient level there will be, variability according to :

[image: Histogram of Age (with replication)]

Also here is the same model fit with ML in lmer:

```
    Linear mixed model fit by REML 
    Formula: totalEEG ~ AgeYrs + MHXKG + log.workDose + (1 | MRN/COURSE) 
       Data: book 
      AIC  BIC logLik deviance REMLdev
     7015 7048  -3500     7006    7001
    Random effects:
     Groups     Name        Variance   Std.Dev.  
     COURSE:MRN (Intercept) 2.7923e-11 5.2842e-06
     MRN        (Intercept) 1.8464e+02 1.3588e+01
     Residual               2.4688e+02 1.5713e+01
    Number of obs: 817, groups: COURSE:MRN, 114; MRN, 103

    Fixed effects:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value
    (Intercept)  31.12003    7.35545   4.231
    AgeYrs        0.10522    0.05946   1.769
    MHXKG         4.57064    3.71167   1.231
    log.workDose  1.14654    0.82651   1.387

    Correlation of Fixed Effects:
                (Intr) AgeYrs MHXKG 
    AgeYrs      -0.504              
    MHXKG       -0.562  0.002       
    log.workDos -0.671 -0.006  0.093
```

And here is a model that has -as far as I can see Age varying only at the Patient level. Fit with Stata:

```
. xtmixed totalEEG MHXKG workDose, || MRN: AgeYrs, covariance(exchangeable)

Performing EM optimization: 

Computing standard errors:

Mixed-effects REML regression                   Number of obs      =       817
Group variable: MRN                             Number of groups   =       103

                                                Obs per group: min =         1
                                                               avg =       7.9
                                                               max =        31


                                                Wald chi2(2)       =     10.60
Log restricted-likelihood = -3504.9961          Prob > chi2        =    0.0050

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    totalEEG |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       MHXKG |   2.434717   3.560351     0.68   0.494    -4.543442    9.412877
    workDose |  -.0102969   .0033165    -3.10   0.002    -.0167971   -.0037966
       _cons |   48.81418   4.001097    12.20   0.000     40.97217    56.65618
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Random-effects Parameters  |   Estimate   Std. Err.     [95% Conf. Interval]
-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------
MRN: Exchangeable            |
            sd(AgeYrs _cons) |   .1967401   .0184842      .1636517    .2365186
          corr(AgeYrs,_cons) |   .9999981   .0007988            -1           1
-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------
                sd(Residual) |   15.86585   .4234722       15.0572    16.71794
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LR test vs. linear regression:       chi2(2) =   160.00   Prob > chi2 = 0.0000

Note: LR test is conservative and provided only for reference.
```

I'd be delighted if somebody could clarify how this works .. or whether I'm getting it wrong.

edit( +2hrs) Having looked back over PinHeiro & Bates I wonder whether:

```
check.fit<-lmer(totalEEG ~ MHXKG + workDose +(AgeYrs|MRN), data=book, family=gaussian(link = "identity"))
```

is more correct?

It produces the same parameter values as above STATA output. However, how would one specify this model in BUGS - or in glmmBUGS to get into BUGS??

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. Could you write the model (with math, not programming code) you're trying to estimate? You seemed to use poisson for the third level, is that correct? If so, it seems to me that that would be a reason for the coeficcients of Bugs and lmer and stata to differ. But in this case, why a poisson to model (hyper)hyperparameters?

Comment: Sure but the question is actually about whether the inclusion of a variable *as if* it varied at the lowest level - including Age in the model as if it varied Treatment to Treatment, even though it is the same number, causes spurious precision - or does it just collapse into the distribution over the patients? If i understood the Math better this wouldn't be quite so much of a problem- Thanks for trying. I'll try to clear it up.